# Publish multiple services under one Sonos Music Partner account

Tags: sonos

We would like to publish multiple services under one Sonos Music Partner account. Our company runs multiple brands in the music industry and would like to publish multiple services accordingly. Just like we do with multiple Android apps (one per brand) under one Google Play Developer account.

We cannot find a way to add a new service to one account. We can only see adding a new version to an existing service.

Is there a known way to handle this? Or do we need to set up a separate account?

Answer (score 0):

Sonos has a one service per account policy. Just create several accounts.